# How to use css compressor (cssmin.js)?

Tags: css, yui-compressor

I'm really interested in compressing my stylesheets using cssmin.js, downloaded the zip on GitHub, but I did not understand how to apply them in my projects.

- In addition to making the call in the header files and style.min.css samaxesjs.min.js, what more do I need?
- It is necessary to send to the server all the files contained in the zip?

I appreciate if anyone can explain in particular the use of this feature.

Website: http://www.phpied.com/cssmin-js/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have node.js installed?

Comment: I thought this was more for if you use a `continuous integration` system to compile/build your project or a build script like `ant` / `nant`, and you include this in the build script to minify your .css on deployment/build.

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks for the clarification, if I have node.js installed on my server, where in I put the files available on GitHub?
https://github.com/stoyan/yuicompressor/blob/master/ports/js/cssmin.js

Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want on-the-fly minification and your website runs node.js, then this is the way to go. However if you only need to minify your CSS before publishing your site and you don't bother doing it every time you change your CSS, then all youn have to do is use the [online demo](http://tools.w3clubs.com/cssmin/) or YUIcompressor.